# THREEJS: How to calculate the closest point on a THREE.ray to another THREE.ray

Tags: javascript, three.js, computational-geometry

I'm using THREE.js and I have two `THREE.Ray` objects. Each ray has an origin (`Vector3`) and a direction (`Vector3`).

I'm trying to figure out how I can get the location on each ray which is the closest point to the other ray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to find the solution, is to know that the line which is formed by the 2 points which are closest to each another, is normal to the 2 rays.

The first step is to find the direction vector of the line which is formed by the 2 closest points. Since the vector is normal to both rays, this can be done by the [Cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).
`rayA` and `rayB` are 2 objects of type `THREE.Ray`:

```js
let Nv = rayA.direction.clone().cross(rayB.direction);
```

The next step is to find a plane for eache ray, which includes the ray and the closest point on the other ray. A plan is formed by 2 vectors, in this case the direction vector of the plane and `nv`. But we need another representation of the plane, by a point and a normal vector. The point is the origin of the ray. The normal vector again can be get by the [Cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product). for the further calculations, this vectors have to be [Unit vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) (length is 1), so they are normalized:

```js
let Na = rayA.direction.clone().cross(Nv).normalize();
let Nb = rayB.direction.clone().cross(Nv).normalize();
```

Now the issue is the intersection of a ray and plan. `ptA` and `ptB` are [`THREE.Vector3`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3) objects and the closest points on the ray:

```js
let Da = rayA.direction.clone().normalize();
let Db = rayB.direction.clone().normalize();

let da = rayB.origin.clone().sub(rayA.origin).dot(Nb) / Da.dot(Nb);
let db = rayA.origin.clone().sub(rayB.origin).dot(Na) / Db.dot(Na);

let ptA = rayA.origin.clone().add(Da.multiplyScalar(da));
let ptB = rayB.origin.clone().add(Db.multiplyScalar(db));
```

---

Explanation to the intersection of a ray and a plane:

[image]

The ray is defined by a point `Ra` and a direction `Da`.
The plane is defined by a point `Rb` and the normal vector `Nb`.

The normal distance `n` of the point `Ra` to the plane is (see [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)):

```
n  =  | Rb - Ra | * cos(alpha)  =  dot(Rb - Ra, Nb)
```

It follows that the distance `da` of the intersection point `ptA` to the origin of the ray Ra is:

```
da  =  n / cos(beta)  =  n / dot(Da, Nb)
```

The intersection point `ptA` is:

```
ptA  =  Ra + Da * da  =  Ra + Da * dot(Rb - Ra, Nb) / dot(Da, Nb)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation and diagram